# How to follow #include statements in a C/C++ project in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, compilation

I am working on a C/C++ project, using Visual Studio.
As many C/C++ projects, a lot of #include clauses are used.

This morning, however, there was the complaint that the basic C++ function `cout` was not recognised.

Using my version management system, I could get back to yesterday's situation and there I see that everything is compiling well, and I can also open the source code, select a `cout` command, and `Go to Definition` or `Go to Declaration`, which brings me to the place where the `cout` command is defined/declared (the Visual Studio `iostream` include file).
In order to get there, my development environment is following the #include clauses in the header of my source files, but from my source file to `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\iostream.cc`  does not go in one step (I don't have `#include <iostream>` in the header of my source file).

I would like to know the list of inclusions which is used for getting to the `iostream.c` file (and if there are different ways to get there, give me all of them).

Is there a way to do this? At this moment my Visual Studio environment has diagnostic as "Tools, Options, Projects and Solutions, Build and Run, MSBuild project build output/log verbosity" but I don't see this in the compilation output.

By comparing these list with the version management differences log, I would like to find out why my project is not compiling anymore.

Comment: Btw, `cout` is C++. Does `std::cout` work? Perhaps someone has removed an errant `using namespace std;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The picture below shows "Show includes" option.

[image]

Comment: Note: This can be done in the compiler settings per file, too.

Comment: @DieterLücking Yes of course. I expect OP to know that "property pages" can be open also per file